# avoid reloading xml multiple times

Tags: php, xml

i want to fetch country source and destination from XML files , it works perfectly in localhost but not in server ,  in server it shows different destination country if i move cursor fastly on map.

in `jquerymap.php`  I  am calling price_by_countries.php file on `mouseover` and `mouseclick` event and I am also passing 2 variables in `price_by_countries.php` and in this file i am loading XML document , I think by loading XMLfile each and every time may cause this problem ..  I  am new to programming and wants to sort it out this issue asap .. thanks

---

jquerymap.php  file code

```
 jQuery.ajax({  type: "POST",
                url: "price_by_countries.php", 
                data: "s="+source+"&d="+destination,
                dataType: 'HTML',
                success: function (msg) {
                             jQuery("#rightinput").html(msg);
                         }
                });
```

price_by_countries  file code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("rd.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

function processXML($node){
   foreach($node->children() as $books  ){  
      if($books['source'] == trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['s'])) && 
         $books['destination'] ==  trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['d']))) 
      {
         echo "<pre>";
         //echo  $books ; 
         echo 'Source Country from XML file = '.$books['source'] . '  ------  Source Country from Textbox = '. trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['s'])) ; 
         echo '<hr>';
         echo 'Destination Country from XML file =  '.$books['destination'] . '  ------  Destination Country from Textbox = '. trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['d'])) ; 
         exit();
      } 
   }
}

processXML($xml);
```

website url : http://realwebit.com/jquerymap/jquerymap.php

Comment: Another simple trick is to wait with the *next* request until a previous one has been finished first. Display something that signals the user that your system is working in the background so the lag (see: [lagging (slang)](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lagging)) is by intention, not by error. - this can be further improved by dropping all new requests in the wait-time but the last. Then take the last one as the next one when the response of the first request has been successfully done. Or cancel the request if your ajax lib allows you that (and the server side process, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be bound to the datarequests on onmouseover. If you move the cursor too fast onmouseover triggers many requests at the same time to the server ! That works on localhost because there is no delay, but not  ! You should install firebug for firefox and take a look at the requests made to the server.

If you dont want to load the xml every time you need a cache:
Save the response of the price_by_countries.php on the client side in an array using source & destination as keys !

If someone clicks or hovers over a country don't call the jquery ajax function right away. Check the array first if you already requested the data and return it ! If not do the ajax request. If it's successfull store the data in the array !

Lucian